# Using Dagger 2.11 with android modular project

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, modularity

I started working on a new Android project from scratch. After understanding the project scope and requested features, I've came up with a modular architecture (basically wrapping every feature into a feature or android module) that looks as following [image]

Everything looks perfect until I wanted to introduce dagger to glue all the modules. The problem is that I want every module to has its own dagger component/subcomponent and it's modules in order to provide dependencies and expose them the graph to be using by other component or the parent one.

Google official dagger documentation states that subcomponents has direct access to parent component dependencies' and not vice versa. However, in my case the base component require dependencies from the data module and this latter itself require dependencies from the network module.

is there any solution for this problem knowing that i want every android module to have its own sub-component preferably? If not, is there any solution anyway?

Thank you.

Edit:
Here is how my project structure looks like

[image]

And this is how I setup my dagger graph

[image]

My AppComponent(Dagger root)

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {
    AppModule.class,
    ActivityBuilder.class,
    AndroidSupportInjectionModule.class
})
public interface AppComponent {

void inject(CatApp application);

@Component.Builder
interface Builder {
    @BindsInstance
    Builder application(Application application);

    AppComponent build();
}
}
```

My App Module

```
@Module(subcomponents = DataComponent.class)
public class AppModule {

@Provides
@Singleton
Context provideContext(Application application) {
    return application.getApplicationContext();
}
}
```

My DataComponent (located at the data android module)

```
@Subcomponent(modules = DataModule.class)
public interface DataComponent {

@Subcomponent.Builder
interface Builder {
    DataComponent build();
}
}
```

Data module (located at data android module) that should provide the implementation of `SystemManager`

```
@Module(subcomponents = NetworkComponent.class)
public class DataModule {

@Provides
@Singleton
ISystemManager provideSystemManager(SystemManager systemManager) {
    return systemManager;
}
}
```

Network Component (located at Network Android Module)

```
@Subcomponent(modules = NetworkModule.class)
public interface NetworkComponent {

@Subcomponent.Builder
interface Builder {
    NetworkComponent build();
}
}
```

Network Module (located at Network Android Module) and should provide implementation of `INetWorkManager`

```
@Module
public class NetworkModule {

@Provides
@Singleton
INetworkManager provideNetworkManager(NetworkManager networkManager) {
    return networkManager;
}
}
```

I am using `@Inject` annotation at all constructors so my configurations is all setup but the issue is that dagger doesn't compiles these subcomponent for some reason and I get this error when compiled:

```
Error:(27, 8) error: [dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T)] com.github.andromedcodes.network.INetworkManager cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
com.github.andromedcodes.network.INetworkManager is injected at
com.github.andromedcodes.data.SystemManager.<init>(networkManager)
com.github.andromedcodes.data.SystemManager is injected at
com.github.andromedcodes.data.di.DataModule.provideSystemManager(systemManager)
com.github.andromedcodes.domain.managers.ISystemManager is injected at
com.github.andromedcodes.domain.interactors.CheckSystemAvailability.<init>(systemManager)
com.github.andromedcodes.domain.interactors.CheckSystemAvailability is injected at
com.github.andromedcodes.chasseautrsor.views.Splash.SplashPresenter.<init>(checkSystemAvailability)
com.github.andromedcodes.chasseautrsor.views.Splash.SplashPresenter is injected at
com.github.andromedcodes.chasseautrsor.di.SplashModule.bindSplashPresenter(presenter)
com.github.andromedcodes.chasseautrsor.views.Contract.Presenter is injected at
com.github.andromedcodes.mvp.BaseActivity.mPresenter
com.github.andromedcodes.chasseautrsor.views.SplashScreenActivity is injected at
dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(arg0)
```

How can I fix this issue knowing that I want to provide ISystemManager implementation at Data android Module and INetworkManager at Network Android Module?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you would like to show us what you have? If you are looking a way to get starting this is my favorite example: https://adityaladwa.wordpress.com/2016/05/11/dagger-2-and-mvp-architecture/

Comment: @DinorahTovar please check my Edit.

Answer (score 0):

Subcomponents automatically have access to objects bound in the parent components' graph, which makes sense, because subcomponents have exactly one parent component—there's no ambiguity. Parent components do not have automatic access to subcomponents' graph because you can create as many subcomponent instances as you'd like; it's not clear which instance you're trying to access. In general, unless you need different variations on an object graph (which you'd do with private modules or child injectors in Guice) or unless you wanted to hide implementation details (e.g. internal network objects), you may be better off installing your modules all in the same Component and skipping the subcomponent strategy.

However, if you do want to separate your graph or create multiple subcomponent instances, you could also *create a subcomponent instance in a scoped `@Provides` method*. That way NetworkComponent has a separate graph with private bindings, but can also use dependencies you expose in AppComponent, and you can also ensure that there is exactly one copy of NetworkComponent and its relevant bindings in your graph. You'll also need to put a getter (provision method or factory method) on the Subcomponent, so you can access some of its bindings from outside, in exactly the same way that you need a getter or injector method on a @Component for it to be useful.

```
@Subcomponent(modules = NetworkModule.class)
public interface NetworkComponent {

  /** Allow anyone with a NetworkComponent instance to get the INetworkManager. */
  INetworkManager getINetworkManager();

  @Subcomponent.Builder
  interface Builder {
    NetworkComponent build();
  }
}

/**
 * Creates a singleton NetworkComponent. Install this in AppComponent's module,
 * or in your data module if that encapsulates network calls.
 */
@Singleton @Provides NetworkComponent networkComponent(
    NetworkComponent.Builder builder) {
  return builder.build();
}

/** Make the INetworkManager accessible, but not the NetworkManager impl. */
@Provides static provideNetworkManager(NetworkComponent networkComponent) {
  return networkComponent.getINetworkManager();  // add this to NetworkComponent
}
```

---

For further reference, see [the "Subcomponents for Encapsulation" section](https://google.github.io/dagger/subcomponents.html#subcomponents-for-encapsulation) on in the Dagger 2 docs on Subcomponents:

> Another reason to use subcomponents is to encapsulate different parts of your application from each other. For example, if two services in your server (or two screens in your application) share some bindings, say those used for authentication and authorization, but each have other bindings that really have nothing to do with each other, it might make sense to create separate subcomponents for each service or screen, and to put the shared bindings into the parent component.
>
> In the following example, the Database is provided within the `@Singleton` component, but all of its implementation details are encapsulated within the DatabaseComponent. Rest assured that no UI will have access to the DatabaseConnectionPool to schedule their own queries without going through the Database since that binding only exists in the subcomponent.

Comment: thank you for the explanation. Though can you please give me what code should i put into each module ? knowing that these dagger modules and components/ subcomponents are each inside their own Android Modules.